# How to print out objects in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have several classes, the first one called "Account" are the objects that are added to the array, the "Account" class has a method called "printAccountDetails" that will print out the details of the account. The second class i'm using is called "AccountCollection" which is the array class, and i've been trying to make a method that will print out the details of all the account objects that have been added to the array.

The closest i've gotten so far is this method:

```
public void printAllAccounts()

{
    if (accounts.length > 0)
    {
        for (int index = 0 ; index < accounts.length ; index++)
        {
            accounts[currentIndex -1].printAccountDetails();
        }
    }

    else

    {
        System.out.println ("No entries");
    }
```

"accounts" is the name of the array, and "currentIndex" is the point in the array. This works for printing out the details however it prints out the account details lots of times which is probably because i've told it to continuously increment by one then go back by 1. But I can't really think of any other way to do it, as this example:

```
public void printAllAccounts()

{
    if (accounts.length > 0)
    {
        for (int index = 0 ; index < accounts.length ; index++)
        {
            accounts[currentIndex].printAccountDetails();
        }
    }

    else

    {
        System.out.println ("No entries");
    }
```

Just leads to a null pointer exception because the current index is blank. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `index` instead of `currentIndex`, since that is your counter variable inside the loop. Where have you defined `currentIndex`?

Comment: In the constructor:     

public AccountCollection(int maxNoOfAccounts)
    {
        accounts = new Account [maxNoOfAccounts];
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

adding index still gives a null pointer exception :/ after printing out the accounts though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you need to use `index` inside the loop, as the value of `currentIndex` will never change in there, hence your seeing the same thing over and over.

Assuming the exception is happening in the code above and not inside `printAccountDetails()` (stack trace would help here), the problem you're having is that one of the elements of your array is null and you're trying to invoke `printAccountDetails()` on it.

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'd have to guess, but I'm assuming `currentIndex` is incremented when you add an item.

So say you add one item, then you have `currentIndex==1` and your first loop will print out the *first* item `accounts[currentIndex -1]` => `accounts[0]` repeatedly - once for each element in the array. Your second loop will throw a `NullPointerException` immediately because `accounts[1]` is `null`.

If you change to using `index` it will throw the exception once `index` reaches `currentIndex` (i.e. `1` in my example).

So the answer (if my assumptions are correct) is not to use the length of the array in the loop condition, but instead use `currentIndex`:

```
    for (int index = 0 ; index < currentIndex ; index++)
    {
        accounts[index].printAccountDetails();
    }
```